# Eclipse Generate Gradle build files not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to move my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and Generate Gradle build files is not generating any file 
I have all the tools... yesterday I've generated a Gradle build file for a project and it work but not now

(I can't post an answer)
to fix the problem I remove the project from eclipse and import it back

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Did you update your android sdk with Android SDK Manager?

Comment: well this is my problem... Generate Gradle build files doesn't generate any file. I could import my project without a Gradle build file but they don't recommend this

Comment: They split the build-tools and platform-tools in the r22 update. A lot of people have been dealing with strange errors as a result. I added an answer since that is the only place to post an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating build.gradle files **FIRST FOR ALL of the projects in my dependencies ONE AFTER ANOTHER** worked for me.

I generated build.gradle (with export wizrd for facebook, play and whatever other projects I imported and used in my project).

This is mentioned in the solution of @alex but I didn't catch it at first reading, hence posting a new response

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For one of my projects, Eclipse did not generate anything.
For anyone having this problem, make sure that any dependency project has a build.gradle file and if it hasn't generate one with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done the r22 update, make sure that you do have the build tools (they separated the packages in r22):

[image]

Click the SDK manager icon in Eclipse. If any of the three packages are not installed, install them and restart Eclipse (probably not necessary, but why take the chance).

Comment: I have all the tools... I forgot to mention that I've generated a Gradle build file for a project yesterday and it work

Comment: so I found that it only doesn't work on my main project because I just generate the file for some libraries that I had.

Comment: Check eclipse's error log: workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log. I ran a recursive and case insensitive grep for gradle from the .plugins directory and saw multiple files with matches, so you might need to look there too for an error message.